# Popup from Firefox Chrome

Tags: javascript, popup, firefox-addon

I am creating a Firefox extension.  I am currently poping up a popup with the following code:

`window.content.document.open(...)`

However, this is causing some big scoping issues.  Is there a way to open a popup with something like this:

`window.open(...)`

Comment: basically the problem with the scoping is that when the popup is closed all the stuff associated with the popup is lost.  In more detail:  A popup is create, it sends an event to the chrome, the chrome sets off a series of events, the popup is closed, the series of events don't take place.  But the series of events do take place if I leave the popup open... hmmm.. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`openWindow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Method/openWindow) and [`openDialog`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.openDialog) and see if one of them suits your purpose.